# how to loop and autoanimate a content slider in jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm going crazy since days trying to make a working slider in jquery (I'm learning it so I'm not so able yet). Finally I came to this, that does work, **but** I'm not able to make it startover after the last slide, nor I know how to autostart it.

Here's the script

```
    $(window).load(function(){

    var nextId = $('div.slide')
    var prevId = $('div.slide')
    var nextAnimation = function(){

        $(nextId).animate({
            left:'-=800px',
            }, 800);
        };

    var prevAnimation = function(){
            $(prevId).animate({
            left:'+=800px',
            }, 800);

        };



        $('.next').click(nextAnimation);



    $('.previous').click(prevAnimation);


});
```

And here's the markup:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="slider" data-slide="0">
    <div id="slide" class="slide first"><img src="00001.jpg" /> </div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide second"><img src="00002.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide third"><img src="00003.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide fourth"><img src="00004.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide fifth"><img src="00005.jpg" /></div>


</div>  
<div class="next">next</div><div class="previous">prev</div>


</div>
```

Finally CSS here:

```
.wrap
{position:relative;
    display:block;
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
border: 2px solid green;
}

.slider
{position:relative;
    display:block;
    width: 4000px;
height: 500px;}

.slide
{position:relative;
display:block;
float:left;
width:800px;
height:500px;}

.slide img
{width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.next
{position:absolute;
    display:block;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 200px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.previous
{position:absolute;
    display:block;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I think I tried everything now ^^'
Can someone help me, please? Thx!

Comment: "I think I tried everything now" - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
   $('div.slide').animate({
      left: "-=800px"
   }, 800, function() {
      // Animation complete.
   });
});
```

Comment: Mmm... it returns a blank space, as before

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Just decreased the width/height of box.

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  var nextId = $('div.slide');
  var prevId = $('div.slide');
  var totalSlides = $(".slider .slide").length; //getting total number of slides present in container
  var currentSlide = 0; //current visible slide number
  var nextAnimation = function() {
    currentSlide++; //moving to next slide
    //checking if we are trying to see slides within our max range
    if (currentSlide < totalSlides) {
      $(nextId).animate({
        left: '-=300px',
      }, 800);
    } else {
      //we are on last slide and trying to move next; so take user to first slide with no animation delay
      currentSlide = 0;
      $(nextId).animate({
        left: '0px',
      });

    }
  };

  var prevAnimation = function() {
    currentSlide--;//descreasing the slide count
    //checking if we are not on first slide; other wise we can't do prev on first slide 
    if (currentSlide > -1) {
      $(prevId).animate({
        left: '+=300px',
      }, 800);
    } else {
      //we are on first slide; so take user to last slide by setting left = - (300 * (totalSlides - 1))
      // for example we have 5 slides; so to show 5th slide:
      // left = - (300 * (5 -1))
      // left = - 300 * 4
      // left = - 1200 px
      currentSlide = totalSlides - 1;
      $(prevId).animate({
        left: '-=' + 300 * currentSlide + 'px',
      });
    }
  };



  $('.next').click(nextAnimation);



  $('.previous').click(prevAnimation);


});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 200px;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.next {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.previous {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="slider" data-slide="0">
    <div id="slide" class="slide first">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide second">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide third">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide fourth">
      4
    </div>
    <div id="slide" class="slide fifth">
      5
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="next">next</div>
  <div class="previous">prev</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Yes! It works! May I ask you a last question then? Can you explain it, if you want, of course! :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: @LuigiBriganti - just updated the snippets with few comments. I hope these will help you.

Comment: Too kind! Thank you very much!